# Merge two data from two columns in 100+ files into one separate file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have large no. of *.txt (from n1.txt to n300.txt) files with the following column.

```
    #1               #2             #3              #4           #5                   #6
0.000000e+00    2.495000e+02    0.000000e+00    5.010000e+02    nan             2.955461e-01
```

I need to extract the data from column 4 and 6 and paste it into a separate file such that column 4 is in ascending order.

I need to repeat it for all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Extract column 4 and 6 from all the files and write it to a tmp file:

```
for file in *.txt;do
  awk '{print $4,$6}' "${file}" >> /tmp/a
done
```

Now sort the contents of that file:

```
sort -g /tmp/a > /tmp/b
```

Depending on how you wish to sort it, change the options on the `sort` command.

Comment: Thanks. How do I save the data from /tmp/a to a .txt file ?

Comment: It is already a text file, you can add the `.txt` extension if you wish. `/tmp/b` is the sorted file.

Comment: You don't need the "unsorted" temp file: `for file in *.txt; do awk '{print $4,$6}' "$file"; done | sort -g > a.txt`

Comment: and no for-loop `awk '{print $4,$6}' n{1..300}.txt | sort -g >a.txt` or `cut -f4,6 n{1..300}.txt | sort -g >a.txt`. add delimiter with `-d' '` if that's Space instead of Tab

Comment: You're quite right, you do not need the unsorted file or the `while` loop. I just thought it made the process a little clearer.